# Zoom/scale ImageView and a small bitmap drawn on it also changes its size

Tags: android, bitmap, zooming, android-canvas

I have an ImageView which i use to draw map tiles. For zooming i use:

```
matrix.postScale(scale, scale, screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

and i draw location marker as a circle on it of 30 pixel radius like below:

```
drawGPSMarker(canvas, locX, locY, 30); //canvas: imageView's canvas
```

which is:

```
public void drawGPSMarker(Canvas canvas, float scrnX, float scrnY, float radius) {

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(450, 450, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas cnv = new Canvas(bitmap);

Paint paint = new Paint();
....
cnv.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, radius, paint );

paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);        
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, scrnX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, scrnY - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, paint);
bitmap.recycle();

}
```

the matter is when i zoom in, imageView is zoomed in and marker bitmap also gets bigger even if its redrawn. Any idea how i can restrict the drawGPSMarker(..) to not grow, I mean it should show same size and thickness regardless of imageView's zoom.

For explaination please see the attached imgage.
[image]

Thoughts please?

Comment: m = new Matrix(); canvas.setMatrix(m);

Comment: Matrix m = new Matrix(); canvas.setMatrix(m); canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, scrnX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, scrnY - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, paint); doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: more help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: do you have custom ImageView and override onDraw ?

Comment: no its standard ImageView and I am drawing data on a bitmap in asynctask and then i use imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: dont do that, extend ImageView and override onDraw method

Comment: @ pskink:
thanks for your suggestion, for this i would need a lot of code changes. but how will this differ by extending by ImageView and overriding onDraw()? Regards

Comment: not ar all, just move all Canvas related dtuff into onDraw merhod which should look luke: canvas.save(); super.onDraw(canvas); canvas.restore(); place_your_drawing_code_here();